# writing DataOutputStream in Android

Tags: android, sockets, stream, tcpclient, dataoutputstream

I am trying to set up a socket client to send just an int for the time being with DataOutputStream to a server. My app works fine when I run it from my PC but I get this error message on Android emulator on Eclipse: "The application SOCKET has stopped unexpectedly please try again". Any tips? If you find any other mistakes why this would not work in general any advice is appreciated.

Code of the app for Android:

```
import java.io.*;  
import java.net.*;  
import android.app.Activity;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SOCKET extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("App1 Test");
        setContentView(tv);
        Client app1Test = new Client();
        app1Test.run();
    }

    public class Client implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int message = 13;
            Socket App1 = null;

                   try {
                     App1 = new Socket("xxxxx.dyndns-remote.com", ####);
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            DataOutputStream output = null;

            try {
                output = new DataOutputStream(App1.getOutputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            try {
                output.write(message);
                output.close(); 
                App1.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: can you provide `logcat` output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the internet permission in your Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

to allow your application to open sockets. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html and http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/AndroidManifest.html.

Comment: omg i ve been busting my head for good 2 hours and i have forgotten that lol. thank you a million man :)

Answer (score 0):

Use an array of bytes to send the data.

```
byte buf [] = message.getBytes ();
output.write(buf);
```

Saludos.